# Delete SharePoint Term Store Translation Package

Tags: 2013

Recently I made a Translation Package for the SharePoint Term Store Manager and uploaded it. I wanted to use the Translated Terms in the Navigation of the Variations.
So I translated the original German Terms into English to use it in the English Variation label. My Problem now is, that even on the German Label the English Translation is displayed.
Can anybody tell me, where I can delete the English Translation Package I uploaded a day ago?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to delete just the Translation Package, so i deleted the whole Group and set it up a second time.